# How do I Iterate over my JSON data questions once a correct answer is given?

Tags: python, json, flask

I am building a simple riddle question-answer game with Python and Flask. My questions and answers are stored in a JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "name": "riddle_0",
    "description": "The more you take, the more you leave behind, what am i?",
    "answer": "footsteps"
  },
  {
    "name": "riddle_1",
    "description": "what has a head, a tail, is brown but has no legs?",
    "answer": "penny"
  },
  {
    "name": "riddle_2",
    "description": "what has many keys, but can't even open a single door?",
    "answer": "piano"
  }
```

I present the questions through a `h1` in the `Game.html` template.

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
            <h1 class="mb-5">{{ username }}</h1>
            <h1 class="mb-5">{{ company_data[0]["description"] }}</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">
            <form method="POST" class="form-inline">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="answer" name="message" id="message" autofocus>
                        <input type="hidden" name="riddle_index" id="riddle_index" value={{riddle_index}}>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Submit Answer</button>
```

accessed through a route

```
@app.route('/game', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def game_questions():
    data = []
    with open("data/company.json", "r") as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        return render_template("game.html", page_title="riddle_me_this", company_data=data)
```

How do I correctly structure my for loop so it iterates over to the next question once a correct answer is given?

Comment: What is `riddle_index`? Is it an actual index, or something like "riddle_1"?

Comment: I was trying to assign some form of integer ID, with the idea that if it has a Riddle_Index=0 sort of Value that i could implement a 'if answer == answer Riddle_Index +1' idea, but yeah, ignore it for now please.

Comment: Ok, so we have to match on the `"answer": "penny"` basis?

Comment: I guess so? Obviously the user input has to == the same as the 'answer' in the particular question they're answering but i am having trouble linking the data to the users input in my For Loop. I imagine there is a very simple syntax that iterates over to the next piece of data "description" once the user input matches the "answer" data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a go at this, and even though there are already good enough answers, I'll post this just to show a slightly different approach.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request
import json

with open("riddle.json", "r") as json_data:
    riddles = json.load(json_data)

app = Flask(__name__)

TEMPLATE_STRING = """
{{riddle['description']}}<br>
<form method="POST" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="answer" name="answer" id="message" autofocus>
    <input type="hidden" name="riddle_id" value="{{riddle_index}}">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Submit Answer</button>
</form>
"""


@app.route('/game', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def game_questions():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        riddle_index = 0
    else:
        riddle_index = int(request.form['riddle_id'])
        if riddles[riddle_index]['answer'] == request.form['answer']:
            riddle_index += 1
            if riddle_index >= len(riddles):
                riddle_index = 0
    return render_template_string(TEMPLATE_STRING, riddle_index=riddle_index, riddle=riddles[riddle_index])
```

If it's a get request, post the first riddle, if it's a post request and the answer is right, post the next riddle, if it's a post request and the answer is wrong, post the same question again. It resets the riddle index if all riddles have been answered, so you can start from the beginning again.

Answer (score 0):

You can json iterate over the json(list of dicts in this case) and check if the answer is correct. If the answer is wrong just break the loop. Example

```
import json
for i in json.loads(your_json_string):
    print('Your Question is: '+i['description'])
    #take answer
    # if ans == i['answer'] #continue for loop
    # else
    # break
```

If you want to maintain the riddle number sort the list first. Example

```
a='''[
  {
    "name": "riddle_0",
    "description": "The more you take, the more you leave behind, what am i?",
    "answer": "footsteps"
  },
  {
    "name": "riddle_3",
    "description": "what has a head, a tail, is brown but has no legs?",
    "answer": "penny"
  },
  {
    "name": "riddle_2",
    "description": "what has many keys, but can't even open a single door?",
    "answer": "piano"
  }]
  '''
newlist = sorted(json.loads(a), key=lambda k: k['name']) # riddle_0,riddle_2,riddle_3
for i in newlist:
    print('Your Question is: '+i['description'])
    print('Your riddle '+i['name'])
    #take answer
    # if ans == i['answer'] #continue for loop
    # else
    # break
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! I'll work on building that for Loop, the only thing i have  trouble understanding is the #Take Answer part, is this where i should link my User Input?

Comment: Yes, you can take the input there and in the next step compare it with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close. I've also captured the riddle index so you wouldn't really need to keep iterating the full list looking for matches.

```
from flask import render_template, request

@app.route('/game', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def game_questions():

    req = request.form.to_dict()
    user_answer = req.get('answer')

    with open("data/company.json", "r") as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)

    questions = [
      {
        "name": "riddle_0",
        "description": "The more you take, the more you leave behind, what am i?",
        "answer": "footsteps"
      },
      {
        "name": "riddle_1",
        "description": "what has a head, a tail, is brown but has no legs?",
        "answer": "penny"
      },
      {
        "name": "riddle_2",
        "description": "what has many keys, but can't even open a single door?",
        "answer": "piano"
      }]

    new_question = None        

    for i, question in enumerate(questions):
        if question['answer'] == user_answer:
            try:
                new_question = questions[i + 1]['description']
                question_index = int(questions[i + 1]['name'].split('_')[1])

            except IndexError:
                new_question = 'No more questions left'
                question_index = None
            break

    context = {'question': new_question, 'riddle_index': question_index}

    return render_template("game.html", page_title="riddle_me_this", 
                           company_data=data, context=context)
```

Comment: This is BEYOND what i was expecting when asking this question, Thankyou very much.

Comment: i have implemented the Code and am given 2 Errors, the first is when i submit a username i am presented with
'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_question' referenced before assignment'

The second is 'Undefined variable Data' on the function 
return render_template("game.html", page_title="riddle_me_this", 
                           company_data=data, context=context)
Which is interesting as i didn't have this before, perhaps the syntax is blocking access to previously written code?

Comment: @Crist0fer fixed both, but the first issue means that you're not getting a matching answer

Comment: ok, I think i understand. i've implemented your edit and am now given the error 'Undefined variable user_answer' I assume i should just write a variable that links to the User input form? To achieve this should i assign that particular form an ID in the HTML? Again, thankyou for your fantastic assistance.

Comment: @Crist0fer gah, I introduced that typo fixing the others.You should be pulling the user answer with `req = request.form.to_dict()` and `user_answer = req.get('answer')` which is referencing the "answer" input tag in your HTML